# NSKeyedUnarchiver won't return data

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am making an app that tracks a user's workouts. I have two custom classes, the first being **ExerciseModel**, which holds the data for each exercise performed during the workout, including the name, sets, reps, etc. Here is my data model:

```
import UIKit

class ExerciseModel: NSObject, NSCoding
{
// MARK: Properties
var name: String
var sets: Int
var reps: Int
var heartrate: Int?
var type: String?

//MARK: Archiving Paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("exercises")


// MARK: Initialization
init?(name: String, sets: Int, reps: Int, heartrate: Int?, type: String)
{

// MARK: Initlaize stored properties
self.name = name
self.sets = sets
self.reps = reps
self.heartrate = heartrate
self.type = type

super.init()


// Initialization should fail if there is no name or sets is negative
if name.isEmpty || sets < 0
    {
        return nil
    }

}

struct PropertyKey
{
    static let nameKey = "name"
    static let setKey = "sets"
    static let repKey = "reps"
    static let heartrateKey = "heartrate"
    static let typekey = "type"
}


// MARK: NSCoding
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: PropertyKey.nameKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(sets, forKey: PropertyKey.setKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(reps, forKey: PropertyKey.repKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(type, forKey: PropertyKey.typekey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.nameKey) as! String
    let sets = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.setKey)
    let reps = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.repKey)
    let heartrate = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.heartrateKey)
    let type = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.typekey) as? String

    // Must call designated initializer
    self.init(name: name, sets: sets, reps: reps, heartrate: heartrate, type: type!)
}

init?(name: String, sets: Int, reps: Int, heartrate: Int, type: String)
{
    // Initialize stored properties.
    self.name = name
    self.sets = sets
    self.reps = reps
    self.heartrate = heartrate
    self.type = type

}


}
```

My second custom class is called **WorkoutStorage**, and this is meant to allow the user to save entire workouts and retrieve them later. The exercise property is an array of ExerciseModel objects, described above. Here is my data model for WorkoutStorage:

```
//

import UIKit

@objc(WorkoutStorage)
class WorkoutStorage: NSObject, NSCoding
{
// MARK: Properties
var name: String
var date: NSDate
var exercises: [ExerciseModel]
var maxHR: Int
var avgHR: Int

// MARK: Archiving Paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("storedWorkouts")

// MARK: Initialization
init?(name: String, date: NSDate, exercises: [ExerciseModel], maxHR: Int, avgHR: Int)
{
    //MARK: Initialize Stored Properties
    self.name = name
    self.date = date
    self.exercises = exercises
    self.maxHR = maxHR
    self.avgHR = avgHR

    super.init()

}

struct PropertyKey
{
    static let nameKey = "name"
    static let dateKey = "date"
    static let exercisesKey = "exercises"
    static let maxHRKey = "maxHR"
    static let avgHRKey = "avgHR"
}

// MARK: NSCoding
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: PropertyKey.nameKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(date, forKey: PropertyKey.dateKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(exercises, forKey: PropertyKey.exercisesKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(maxHR, forKey: PropertyKey.maxHRKey)
    aCoder.encodeInteger(avgHR, forKey: PropertyKey.avgHRKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.nameKey) as! String
    let date = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.dateKey) as! NSDate
    let exercises = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.exercisesKey) as! [ExerciseModel]
    let maxHR = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.maxHRKey)
    let avgHR = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.avgHRKey)

    // Must call designated initializer
    self.init(name: name, date: date, exercises: exercises, maxHR: maxHR, avgHR: avgHR)
}
}
```

I followed the Apple tutorial for Persist Data to set up NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver for this, but I am still having trouble retrieving my data. When I try to load the Workouts, I call the following function:

```
func loadStoredWorkouts() -> WorkoutStorage
{
    NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(WorkoutStorage.self, forClassName: "WorkoutStorage")
    NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("WorkoutStorage", forClass: WorkoutStorage.self)

    print("\(WorkoutStorage.ArchiveURL.path!)")

    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(WorkoutStorage.ArchiveURL.path!) as! WorkoutStorage
}
```

Currently I can only return a single WorkoutStorage object, but when I attempt to retrieve an array containing all the stored WorkoutStorage objects, I get an error saying: **Could not cast value of type 'Workout_Tracker.WorkoutStorage' (0x1000fcc80) to 'NSArray' (0x19f6b2418)**. I have read a lot of documentation trying to figure out why this will only return a single object, as well as checked out questions with similar issues, but to no avail. I originally set up my app following the Apple Persist Data tutorial to store and load my **ExerciseModel** objects, and that seems to work flawlessly. I set up the **WorkoutStorage** class the same way, but there seems to be an issue here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

**Edit*
Here is the code I use to archive the WorkoutStorage object:

```
func saveWorkoutStorageObject(currentWorkout: WorkoutStorage)
    {
        NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(WorkoutStorage.self, forClassName: "WorkoutStorage")
        NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("WorkoutStorage", forClass: WorkoutStorage.self)

    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(currentWorkout, toFile: WorkoutStorage.ArchiveURL.path!)
    if !isSuccessfulSave
    {
        print("Failed to save exercises")
    }
    if isSuccessfulSave
    {
        print("Successful save of current workout: \(currentWorkout)")
    }
}
```

Workouts are only created one at a time by the user, so each time one is completed, I pass the object to the above function to archive it.

To unarchive all the objects, I was trying to do something along the lines of:

```
var workouts = [WorkoutStorage]()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    workouts = loadStoredWorkouts()
}
```

where the loadStoredWorkouts() function would be:

```
 func loadStoredWorkouts() -> [WorkoutStorage]
    {
        NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(WorkoutStorage.self, forClassName: "WorkoutStorage")
        NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("WorkoutStorage", forClass: WorkoutStorage.self)

    print("\(WorkoutStorage.ArchiveURL.path!)")

    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(WorkoutStorage.ArchiveURL.path!) as! [WorkoutStorage]
}
```

Comment: One small point I noticed (which isn't the cause of the problem you are reporting) is that your exercise model `init` should declare `type` as `String?` and then you should remove the `!` from `type` when you call init from the decoder init

Comment: Can you show the code where you archive and unarchive an array of `WorkoutStorage` objects?  Also, CoreData would probably be a better choice for this

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for that Paul. I have updated my question to show that info

Comment: Your `saveWorkoutStorageObject` only archives a single workout. It doesn't archive the array, so of course you can't unarchive an array. You need to archive the `workouts` array if you want to be able to unarchive an array.  Each time you archive something to a file you replace the contents of the file. It doesn't append to the end.

Comment: @Paulw11 I see...that makes sense. So if I were to save an array with the first workout, then before I saved what would be the second workout, I could just load the array, append to it and then save that, effectively overwriting the data? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yeah, when you save, just archive the array (and because the objects in the array conform to `NSCoding`, it just "works").

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure why you're calling `setClass` and `setClassName`. You usually don't need to do that, so I wonder why you're doing that here...

Comment: Yes, but that is why I suggested you look at Core Data. It is a database-like object persistence framework, where you can just save a new object and it gets added to the data store.  Xcode will even create the object model classes for you

Comment: @Paulw11 Awesome, thanks guys. I guess when I set my ArchiveURL using the URLByAppendingPathComponent method I was under the impression it was constantly appending the info at the URL. Thanks so much for your help, I will definitely look into Core Data. How do I get you credit for the answer here?

Comment: I will add an answer...

Comment: @Paulw11 could you possibly point me in the direction of a solid tutorial for Core Data? Thanks again!

Comment: I can't personally recommend one, but Google found this https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial and Ray Wenderlich tutorials are normally pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `saveWorkoutStorageObject` only archives a single workout. It doesn't archive the array, so of course you can't unarchive an array.

You need to archive the `workouts` array if you want to be able to unarchive an array.

Each time you archive something to a file you replace the contents of the file. It doesn't append to the end.

Since `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject` automatically archives child objects, all you need to do is archive the array and your `WorkoutStorage` objects will be archived automagically

```
func saveWorkouts(workouts:[WorkoutStorage])
{
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(workouts, toFile: WorkoutStorage.ArchiveURL.path!)
    if isSuccessfulSave
    {
        print("Successful save of workouts: \(workouts)")
    } else {
        print("Failed to save exercises")
    }
}
```